# How to nextLine in a FileWriter and BufferedWriter, in java?

Tags: java, filereader, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I've been trying to work with some files but It never goes to the next Line.
With "\r\n" or by using bufferedWriter, at first I only used fileWriter.

How do I make a nextLine() ? These files will be used on Unix, I heard it is not the same character recognized for going to the next line.

Here is What my program looks like :

```
try {

    File tempFile = new File(pathFiles + "tmp.txt");
    //System.out.println(tempFile);     //TEST
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile, true);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    Reader fr = new FileReader(fileOriginal);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    String line = "";
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayToConvert.size(); i++) {
            line = line.replace(arrayToConvert.get(i),
                    arrayConverted.get(i));
        }
        //line += "\r\n";   
        //line += "\u240D";
        //System.getProperty("line.separator");
        //br.readLine().split("[\\r\\n]+");
        //br.write(line);
        bw.write(line);
        bw.newLine();


        //br.readLine().split("[\\r\\n]+");
        //line.split("[\\r\\n]+");
    }

    bw.close();
    fw.close();
    br.close();
    fr.close();
```

This is the section you need. In comment, what I already tried.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `br.newLine()` should work and is platform independent, but shouldn't the buffered writer writes and newline be called within the for loop? Or am I greatly confused? Myself, I'd use a PrintWriter's `println(...)` method.

Comment: `bw.newLine()` writes a platform dependent newline separator, which is not always going to be `\r\n`.  You're aware of that?

Comment: Did you checked the content of the file? Even not visible character ? Building a file on a OS to be read in another will not necessary work

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `BufferedWriter` in a [`PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) and use the `println()` methods.

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);

pw.println(line);
```